# Nothing clickable on screen except slider images

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a webpage on which I am redesigning the layout. It has images in a slider which references something called LasteventImg if that's any help? Anyway, I'm stuck now where I can only click on the slider images but The textbox and hyperlinks above the slider are not clickable on mobile devices.

I have tried adding position:relative to the DIV which surrounds the textboxes and hyperlinks code and that works.. you can click on them but not on the slider images. It's only allowing one or the other.

Any help appreciated.

CSS

```
.lasteventimg { width:100%; height:640px; overflow-x:scroll; overflow-y:hidden; margin-top:5px; }
.lasteventimg ul { list-style:none; display:block; white-space:nowrap; }
.lasteventimg ul li { width: 60px; display:inline; }

.lasteventimg img
{
border:1.5px solid #333;
}
```

ASP

```
<div runat="server" id="usersStall">
    <div class="lasteventimg" >
        <div class="stallRow1">
            <ul id="stallRow1UL" runat="server">
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="stallRow2nd" runat="server">
            <ul id="stallRow2UL" runat="server">
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div style="text-align:center; position:relative; clear:both;  margin-top:-583px;">              
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtItem" runat="server" visible="false" height="10px" style="font-size: 1.1em" Columns="15" MaxLength="255"></asp:TextBox>
    <br>  
    <asp:HyperLink ID="hypShareLink" runat="server" ><asp:Image ID="imgAvatar" width="80px" runat="server" /></asp:HyperLink>                            
</div>
```

Comment: Please take the time to produce [mcve] so that we can try to help you.

Comment: Probably you have  a transparent element upon the textbox.

Comment: Thanks @Mederic I have now added a bit of the code. It is just HUGE.. it was written for me and I'm just learning how to change things. The top part of the ASP code displays pictures of items sellers on my site are selling in a slider type thing. The bottom part contains some hyperlinks and text box which can't be clicked on.

Comment: @FarzinKanzi Yeah that sounds like what's happening but I'm a novice.. Is there any easy way to figure out what it is? Many thanks.

Comment: If I hold my finger on the screen where the text box or hyperlinks are (On my phone) then it highlights the slider as if i'm selecting that so it must be transparently over the top of it somehow.

Comment: Could it be that big Margin I'm using ? margin-top:-583px;

Comment: I've just took the margins out and it still won't work.

Comment: You can set your browser (firefox or chrome) to responsive view and set it to your mobile size. Then you can use the inspector of browser to see what the problem is.

Comment: Thanks @FarzinKanzi I've been trying to do that but not sure how to use Inspect effectively enough to locate the problem.